# How correctly insert values in table using Doctrine ORM?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I use Symfony2 and Doctrine ORM. I have table "articleType" where I keep all possible article types. I need insert several values to that table only once, when table is created. My question is how and where I should do that? Because I just can't insert that values in controller with every request to that controller right? Maybe I should write down manually that inserts in Doctrine  migration class?

Comment: Many possibilities. You could make an install command for the console: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, but most of the time [Doctrine Migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) are the way to go. Each migration is supposed to be applied just once and that's exactly what you need.